# How to open Storyboard as xml source?

Tags: xcode, storyboard

I need to reorder `View controllers` in my `Storyboard`. I know that I need to open `Storyboard` as source code using right clicking on the file and using menu `Open as...`. Then I can open `Storyboard` as `xml` file.

My problem is sometimes the source is opened as text - there are no colour differences on the comments for example. Also when I make move of the code inside it is not indented properly.

How to open `Storyboard` source as `xml`?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

To open Storyboard as XMl source:

[image]Right click on your storyboard, you will see a menu, hover over **"Open As"**  then select **"Source Code"**

Hope this will help.

[image]

To go back to view storyboard in the design build mode,

Right click on your storyboard, you will see a menu, hover over **"Open As"** then select **"Interface Builder -- Storyboard"**

Answer (score 2):

If Xcode can't open the file .nib or .storyboard ( may be because of merge conflict ) then you can open in textEdit

open  -a textEdit